# Academia and Graphic Design are missing from Meta’s icon cloud

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, meta

Here is the icon cloud from Meta SE’s header with somewhat enhanced contrast:

[image: Meta icon cloud]

I can find every graduated site represented up there except Graphic Design and Academia. Interestingly, Salesforce, which graduated later, is represented (in the lower right).

These are the missing logos for those who want to seek themselves:

[image: Graphic Design logo]
[image: Academia Design logo]

Comment: I'm... not sure that we have a plan to keep this logo 100% up to date with every site logo forever and ever. But, well spotted. ;)

Comment: @AnnaLear What do you mean? You'd only ever be adding *one more* at a time, that's barely anything!

Comment: @MatthewHaugen More that we're gonna forget. Inevitably.

Comment: Since MSE has a more... generic header and footer, no longer reproducible?